# The best zip library with public domain license

Tags: c++, c, zip

Does anyone know zip library of C/C++ in public domain license?

It meets the following requirements.

1. It operates by the unit like stb_image.c library
2. Supported cross platform. Windows, Mac, Linux and so on.
3. Language is C/C++
4. License is public domain.

Comment: "Public domain" has a very specific meaning; is that what you really meant?  What are the license requirements that you need. Can you manage with something less than public domain, such as BSD license or LGPL?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. There is no such thing as a "public domain license". If it's public domain, it doesn't need a license. In fact, if it's public domain it *cannot have* a license, since a license is issued by the copyright holders, but public domain works by definition *do not have* copyright holders.

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag: That definitely does make sense. Copyright is by default, in order to make something public domain the copyright owner must willfully do that - release his work into public domain. That can be considered licensing - granting other people rights to use the work.

Answer (score 26):

I'd recommend [ZipLib](https://bitbucket.org/wbenny/ziplib/wiki/Home).

Personal reasons why I love this project:

- **built around c++11 stl streams** (e.g. decompresses into STL streams!)
- lightweight (no dependencies other than zlib)
- can be used on both windows & linux

It took me a long time to find this project -- hope this helps someone.

Comment: After hours (burning into a second day) of attempting the other libraries (minizip, the fork of minizip (both using ZLib), and others) - this is the only one that built seamlessly on Windows and also in 64-bit - it includes all dependencies (ZLib, bzip, lzma) internally so you don't need to waste time & hassle with paths, build types, installations, and managing multiple external repositories just for .zip support - it just builds out-of-the-box as a single, standalone repository with no dependencies (though uses ZLib) and is easy to use.  Highly recommended!  Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: we have one issue on this library at the moment, it has no namespace. it got conflicted to other zip library used by an engine we are using. we prefer not used that included zip lib in the engine because it doesn't have the feature we need so we searched for another ziplibrary.

Comment: We've been using this for years, and one thing to note is that on Linux and MacOs, the library is very fast, but compression is very slow on Windows (around 15 times slower for the same file as on Unix)

Comment: FYI, in case anyone tries a CLI build on Windows with gcc (it was 13.2 of [w64devkit](https://github.com/skeeto/w64devkit) for me), I had to disable `-fPIC` in `CFLAGS`, add `-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE` to `CXXFLAGS`, and exclude the `lzma/unix/*.c` sources from the build for it to compile.

Answer (score 20):

It didn't yet exist when the question was asked. But it does now: [miniz](https://github.com/richgel999/miniz) - public domain, single C file, explicitly inspired by the likes of stb_image.

Comment: Worth noting that miniz is no longer public domain, recent versions have switched to MIT license. (The MIT licensed part was ZIP64 support. If you have an older version before ZIP64 support was merged in, that is still public domain.)

Comment: There are sample files to compress strings and single files. But I could not find a sample to compress multiple files with filenames into a ZIP file.

Answer (score 11):

The most popular open source zip implementation is [Info-Zip](http://www.info-zip.org/). Deflate algorithm used in zip file format is implemented by [zlib](http://zlib.net/) library. Both are released on liberal, BSD-like license, but not public domain.

Comment: It is not Public Domain, but I try using it. Thanks!

Comment: It's not a library and not good source code. Well it's dating back to 1992, what can we expect.

Answer (score 6):

It's not public domain, but [Minizip](http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/minizip.html), which is included with [zlib](http://www.zlib.org), meets your other three requirements. It also contains miniunz.c, a very easy to follow zip/unzip example.

Comment: Oh, It serves as a reference. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Public Domain is the LZMA sdk from 7z
http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html

Problem: the documentation is "not existing" :-(

Comment: I believe the SDK requires 7z.dll, which is LGPL.

Comment: Where do you get that information. You do not need to use 7z.dll to use LZMA compression (7z and xz files). The SDK does not depend on 7z.dll.

Comment: Seems no one is still maintaining this project.

Comment: latest release 2016-10-04
this is quite current, Why to you think "no one is maintaining"?

Answer (score 2):

The closest I can think of would be [Xz-utils](http://tukaani.org/xz/), which uses the public domain LZMA SDK. It's not zip, *per se*, nor does it use the deflate algorithm, but it is one of the few compression libraries in the public domain.

Comment: Thanks! It serves as a reference!

Comment: To my understanding, the LZMA SDK requires 7z.dll in order to operate (which is LGPL).

Comment: @BillyONeal: Not as far as I've seen. LZMA stands on its own. Perhaps 7z.dll depends on LZMA? Neither of those libraries depend on the other on my system, and none of the build scripts for LZMA depend on 7zip, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.bzip.org/ is pretty common and a requirement of tons of easy_installs in multiple target languages.

> **Update:**
>   I realize this is wrong, but it's a common misunderstanding, so I'm leaving it up as a sentinel to describe a frequent error.

Comment: bzip uses Burrows-Wheeler compression algorithm, whereas zip uses Deflate algorithm.

Comment: @el.pescado: was this a requirement that I missed?

Comment: Despite name similarities, bzip2 != zip

Comment: not only bzip2 but also gzip (and many other formats) is different [*There are numerous other standards and formats using "zip" as part of their name. For example, zip is distinct from gzip, and the latter is defined in an IETF RFC (RFC 1952) \[...\] Likewise, the ZLIB format (IETF RFC 1950) also uses the DEFLATE compression algorithm, but specifies different headers for error and consistency checking. Other common, similarly named formats and programs with different native formats include 7-Zip, bzip2, and rzip.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)#Legacy)