# What is a good and optimized way to run shell command in a pthread?

Tags: c++, pthreads, posix, freebsd

Basically, I want to compress a file in a pthread thread using gzip. 
The first solution that pops up in mind and on Google is to call system().

What does the stackoverflow community suggest?

1. Shall I use system() in a pthread?
2. Or shall I myself just fork and exec in pthread? But since pthread is a thread, is it advisable to do a fork() and exec() in pthread thread?
3. Or what is the better approach than the above?

Comment: You dont expect the compression to be faster just because you call gzip via `system` from within a phtread, do you? "There are many discussions about system() being expensive" first time i hear that, can you give a reference? Also please choose one language

Comment: Why not use a gzip library?

Comment: You could get a [zip library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220549/the-best-zip-library-with-public-domain-license) and avoid `system` altogether.

Comment: If functions such as `system()` were actually "expensive and should be avoided", how could any multithreaded process start a child process that doesn't violate that?  Because under the hood, to start any child process requires pretty much a `fork()` and then an `exec()` call - or the exact equivalent.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I'm not sure anyone hear is saying that.  And, from what I have seen and know, most people agree that spinning up a thread is expensive and can outweigh any performance gain you would get from running the task in parallel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You shouldn't use `system` for this, but not because it's expensive.  (For any file that is worth bothering to compress, the overhead of *any* technique for invoking a background gzip compression is negligible relative to the cost of doing the compression itself.)  The reason you shouldn't use `system` is, `system` invokes a shell, and that means you have to worry about quoting the arguments.  If you use `fork` and `execvp` instead, you don't have to worry about quoting anything.
2. The problems associated with mixing `fork` and `wait` with threads are real, but they are tractable.  If your OS has `posix_spawn`, it will take care of some of those problems for you.  I don't normally recommend `posix_spawn` because code that uses it is, in general, harder to maintain than code that uses `fork`, but for this application it should be OK.  I cannot fit a comprehensive guide to mixing `fork` and `wait` with threads into this answer box.
3. An alternative you should consider is compressing the data in the thread that would be waiting for the `gzip` process, using [zlib](https://www.zlib.net/).  This avoids the problems of mixing `fork` and `wait` with threads, but it adds a library dependency to your program, which may not be as convenient as relying on an external `gzip` executable.

Answer (score 2):

Start with `system` call in another thread and only add complexity when needed.

The extra complexity of doing `fork`/`exec` or using a `zip` library is only worth the effort if `system` is not sufficient for some reason (i.e. you want to redirect both `stdin` and `stdout` of the child process into your parent process, or your want to compress a file in memory for sending it over the network without writing new files).

Comment: The thread that I'm creating is meant for compression only. It's already a separate thread created via pthread_create to go and compress the file.

Could you please elaborate more about what you meant?

Comment: @C_user5 Added more words for you.

Comment: Any use of `system` involving arguments to the subprocess is practically guaranteed to have shell quotation bugs.

Comment: @zwol Quoting a filename with `''` is straightforward.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Straightforward. Sure. *hollow, bitter laughter*

Comment: @zwol If you do need to handle evil filenames with special symbols in them then sure, doing `fork`/`exec` to avoid quoting is worth it.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I believe the claim I am making is that you _always_ need to handle arbitrarily evil filenames, and that in my experience the code to do shell quotation correctly is nastier and harder to get right than the code to do fork+exec.

Comment: @zwol I prefer _it depends_ to _always_.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I cannot agree with that.

Comment: @zwol We agree to disagree agreeably.