# Is there a way to extract a zip file (in both Windows and Linux) without using any external libraries in QT C++?

Tags: qt

I want to download a zip file from the internet and then extract its content. So far, I have been able to completely download the file from the source. Now for the extraction part, I came across libraries such as quazip, but, since we get the option of extracting a .tar.xz file in Linux and a .zip file in Windows, I wonder if there is any way of extracting these files without using any external libraries such as quazip.

This is my code so far

```
    QDialog dialog(this);
    QFormLayout form(&dialog);
    QProgressBar pb(this);
    QLabel *label = new QLabel(this);
    label->setText("Update progress");
    form.addRow(label);
    form.addWidget(&pb);
    dialog.show();
    QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    QUrl url("downloadUrl");
    QNetworkRequest request(url);
    QNetworkReply *reply = manager->get(request);

    QString path = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::DownloadLocation) + "/fileToDownload.zip";
    ui->textBrowser->setText(path);
    QFile *file = new QFile(path);
    file->open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);

    connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::readyRead, [=]() {
        file->write(reply->readAll());
    });

    connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, [&]() {

        reply->deleteLater();
        dialog.deleteLater();
    });

    connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::downloadProgress, [&](qint64 bytesReceived, qint64 bytesTotal) {
        qInfo() << "Downloaded" << bytesReceived << "of" << bytesTotal << "bytes.";
        processProgress(bytesReceived, bytesTotal, &pb);
    });

    QEventLoop loop;
    connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, &loop, &QEventLoop::quit);
    loop.exec();
```

Comment: I don't think Qt can do this. So your best bet might be to find a library with liberal enough open source license, and just add it as part of your own project, if depending on a fully external library is a no-no. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/q/3220549/1717300

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use `QZipReader`. Unfortunately, it's a private class, not a public API, so you'll have to download its header from [Qt source code](https://codebrowser.dev/qt5/qtbase/src/gui/text/qzipreader_p.h.html).

Then you just include it and do something like this (I took it from an existing project as is):

```
QZipReader zip(path);
    
auto files = zip.fileInfoList();
    
for (const auto &fileInfo : files)
{
    if (fileInfo.isDir)
        Utils::createDir(Utils::concatPaths(destination, fileInfo.filePath));
    else
        Utils::createDir(Utils::concatPaths(destination, QFileInfo(fileInfo.filePath).path()));
}
    
if (!zip.extractAll(destination))
    return false;            
    
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// WORKAROUND
for (const auto &fileInfo : files)
{
    if (!fileInfo.isDir && !fileInfo.isFile && !fileInfo.isSymLink)
    {
        // bug; do workaround here
        auto data = zip.fileData(fileInfo.filePath);
        QFile file(Utils::concatPaths(destination, fileInfo.filePath));
        if (!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly) || data.size() != file.write(data))
            return false;
        file.close();
    }
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Note, that it's possible to use this class to extract zip files from both memory and files on disk.

To extract from memory, use `QZipReader(QIODevice *device)` constructor. Example:

```
QBuffer buffer(&byteArray);
buffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
QZipReader zip(&buffer);
```